# How many positive integral values of $n$, less than $100$, are there such that $n^3+72$ is completely divisible by $n+7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many positive integral values of $n$, less than $100$, are there such that $n^3+72$ is completely divisible by $n+7$ ?

MY WORK :-

Well we know that $a+b$ divides $a^3+b^3$ thus $n+7$ divides $n^3+7^3$ thus it divides $n^3+343$. Now if $n+7$ divides $n^3+72$ then it divides their difference. Thus $n+7$ divides $343-72=271$. Now the factor of $271$ are $1$ and $271$ only. So if $n\lt100$ then there are no values possible; hence answer should be $0$. However in answer key it's said $1$. I want to know why it's $1$ ??

Comment: I agree that the answer is $0$.  Brute force confirms.

Comment: Maybe the author of the answer key misread it as $n^3 - 72$.

Comment: @daniel you seem to be correct.  It appears that $(76+7)|(76^3-72)$ is the only solution within scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the polynomial division with remainder:
$${n^3+72\over n+7}=n^2-7n+49-{271\over n+7}\ .$$
Now $n^2-7n+49$ is an integer for all $n$. Therefore it remains to check, for which $n\in[100]$ the number $271$ is divisible by $n+7$.

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did only a quick search with the following bound: $1\le\text{n}\le10^2$.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[IntegerQ[(n^3 + 72)/(n + 7)], n, Nothing], {n, 1, 
   10^2}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]=Nothing
```

What implies that there are no solutions. If I extend the search to $1\le\text{n}\le10^8$ I found:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[IntegerQ[(n^3 + 72)/(n + 7)], n, Nothing], {n, 1, 
   10^8}] //. {} -> Nothing

Out[2]={264}
```

Which means that $\text{n}=264$ is a solution, because:

$$\frac{264^3+72}{264+7}=67896\tag1$$